# Number of empty boxes after n balls have been distributed

Tags: probability

Given m boxes into which balls are thrown independently, and uniformly,i.e probability of a ball falling into a box is 1/m for all boxes. Let
Nn denote the number of empty boxes after n balls have been distributed.

(b) Let n, m $\to \infty$ in such a way that $\dfrac{n}{m} \to \lambda$ . Prove that
$$\dfrac{N_n}{n} \to^{p} c $$

and determine the constant c.

My first approach was to consider $$Nn=\sum_{i=1}^{m} 1_{A_i}$$

Where $A_i =$ The box $i$ is empty. And I thought about trying to use some inequality like Tchebychev, but I think in the end I will not be able to find a specific constant $c$.

Edit:
$$E[N_n] = \sum_{i=1}^{m} E[1_{A_i}] =\sum_{i=1}^{m} P(A_i) = m\Bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{m}\Bigg)^{n}$$

Comment: How far did you get with your first approach? Were you able to write out the expected value?

Comment: Yes. I will add the expected value that I found.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Since we have a sum of $m$ identical terms, so I'd expect a coefficient of $m$ (though it might get cancelled out).

Comment: I'm not sure. My idea was: I have n throws and the probability of a ball don't fall into a box is $1-\dfrac{1}{m}$, so, after n throws, there is $\Bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{m}\Bigg)^n$ chance of none of the balls fall into this specific box. And I extended this idea to de m boxes.

Comment: The corrected version makes sense now. Also remember to divide out by $n$ (yes it's in the probability, and we're only focused on expected value right now). How can you make use of $n/m$ being mostly a constant?

Comment: I'm stuck at this part. I don't know if I'm missing something. The first thing that comes in my mind is some kind of exponential result in $\dfrac{\Bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{m}\Bigg)^n}{n} = \lambda e$ since m and n are going to infinity, but I don't know if I can do this. But I'm using the expected value instead of the actual sum of the indicators.

Comment: What do you know about $( 1 - 1/m) ^m $ as $m$ approaches infinity?

Comment: I know that $(1 - 1/m)^m$ goes to $1/e$ as m goes to infinity.

Comment: Great. Now force that out. Remember that the only other constant is n/m, so we don't want to see m or n by themselves. In particular (highlight to see content), $\color{white} { E[N_n] / N \rightarrow 1/\lambda e^{-\lambda} }$.

Comment: I will try to wrap everything to see if I'm understanding. Following your comments, the idea is to use the fact that convergence in mean imply convergence in probability, right?

Comment: I'm much less confident about the probability convergence because there are various theorems/laws to apply with different conditions and it's been a while since I used them. At least this provides you with what the $c$ value is, and then you can check. $\quad$ My suspicion is that you'd need to use Chebyshev inequality, which requires showing that the variance is small enough.

Comment: Now I understand. I think I understood your remarks and I will try to do and write here. But, one last question. To use some kind of Law of Large numbers, and to affirm that the sum over n converges to the mean, I don't have to have a sum of independent random variables? Can i say that the indicators are independent?

Comment: The indicators are not independent. You can heuristically argue that they are negatively correlated, since if we know that Box 1 is empty, it's more likely that Box 2 is not empty. We can still find the variance using variance and covariance of $I_i, I_j$.   $\quad$ Note that LOLN doesn't apply to this case, because your $I_1$ is changing for each $n$.

Comment: Right, I think that now I fully understood the problem and the ideas behind. So: $E[\dfrac{Nn}{n}] = \dfrac{m}{n}\Bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{m}\Bigg)^n  = \dfrac{\lambda}{e}$. And now I can proceed to obtain the variance of the sum and find $P(|Sn/n - E[Sn/n]| > \epsilon)$ by aplying Chebyshev, right?

Comment: I'm kind of lost now. But, if the indicators(Bernoulis) are not independent, how can I affirmate that the variance of the sum will be a binomial?

Comment: Oh true. Guess we do have to do it via variance and covariance then (let me delete the previous comment).

Comment: No problem. I will try to resolve the entire question using the Chebyshev Inequality later today and post here.